# insert data in associative array based on condition PHP

Tags: php, arrays, push, associative

I have two arrays:

`$sizes` and `$percentages`

`$sizes` looks like this:

```
 "sizes":{"0":{"size_id":5,"it":"50","us":"32"},"1":{"size_id":4,"it":"48","us":"30"}},
```

and `$percentages` like this:

```
"percentages":[{"5":"70"},{"4":"30"}]
```

I want to insert the data from percentage in the $sizes array based on $key value of percentage being = to "size_id" in $sizes and end with this:

```
"sizes_with_percentage":{"0":{"size_id":5,"percentage":70,it":"50","us":"32"},"1":{"size_id":4,"percentage":30"it":"48","us":"30"}},
```

I tried some nested loops but I didn't find a proper way, and array_push_assoc returns a "call to undefined bla bla error".

Comment: you mix curly and square brackets by typos, or your origin is a JSON string? “undefined bla bla error” doesn't exists: please report exact error (undefined index?) and relative code line. BTW, is the origin is a JSON the error can due to call to an object instead of an array. But you have to post JSON string and your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have first used `json_decode` to create real arrays here:

```
$sizes = json_decode('{"0":{"size_id":5,"it":"50","us":"32"},"1":{"size_id":4,"it":"48","us":"30"}}', true);
$percentages = json_decode('[{"5":"70"},{"4":"30"}]', true);
```

You can build a `$final` array pretty simply.

First loop through sizes, add them to `$final`, using the `size_id` as the array key. This will make the following step much easier.

```
foreach($sizes AS $size) {
    $final[$size['size_id']] = $size;
}
```

Now loop through percentages, and use the key to find the right `$final` entry, and add the percentage element.

```
foreach($percentages AS $percentage) {
    $final[key($percentage)]['percentage'] = current($percentage);
}
```

You're done! If you don't want the `$final` array to still by keyed by `size_id` you can remove that:

```
$final = array_values($final);
```

And of course if you want the output to be json:

```
$finalJson = json_encode($final);
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/LR8Tv

Comment: thanks, both $sizes and $percentages are php arrays [] ... I think the output is parsed by Json Formatter extension in chrome hence the confusion. I tried this code (only the second part, no json_decode) and it works.